# Why is make not rebuilding when source files are changed?

Tags: c, makefile, cs50

I am currently attempting problem set 4 (speller) from the CS50 course. It is the first problem set where we have multiple header files and multiple source files, so they gave us a Makefile to use, to compile each .c file into .o, then link the .o files to form the compiled binary.

This is the makefile

```
speller:
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o
```

Output of ls:

```
dictionaries  dictionary.h  keys      speller    speller.o dictionary.c  dictionary.o  Makefile  speller.c  texts
```

When I run make for the first time, it compiles speller no problems. However, when I make changes in dictionary.c and save it (In particular, I purposely screwed up all my printf() calls to printasdasdsa() yeah you get it) and I run make, it keeps saying `make: 'speller' is up to date`, and just refuses to rebuild even though I made changes to dictionary.c's source.

Any idea what's wrong with the way I'm building speller? Is there something wrong with my makefile?

I know that there's a way to force make to rebuild by passing the "-B" flag, but is it convention to always do it that way whenever you make a change in your code?

This is the task: https://docs.cs50.net/2019/x/psets/4/speller/hashtable/speller.html

Comment: `speller` has no dependencies and is not `.PHONY`.   Your recipe generates `speller`, which is at that point up-to-date (so no need to rebuild....)    I'll post an answer with some details.

Comment: ... so yes, if you (reasonably) expect `make` to rebuild your program if run after one of its sources changes then the makefile is indeed flawed.  Not necdessarily "wrong", *per se*, but distinctly oversimplified and underpowered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make only rebuilds a target if the target does not exist, or the target is older than one of its dependencies.   In your case you have a target `speller`, with no dependencies.   The first time you run it, make checks, and doesn't find it, so it builds it.    The next time you build, it checks, the file exists, and since it does not have any dependencies, it does not rebuild.   You would want to do something like:

```
speller:  speller.c dictionary.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o
```

Or, better yet:

```
speller: speller.o dictionary.o
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o

speller.o: speller.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c

dictionary.o: dictionary.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
```

Which would not rebuild the .o files unless the .c files changed, and would not rebuild the app unless one of the .o files was rebuilt.   Note that *neither* of these two handle any header files.   If your .c files include any local headers, those need to be added to the dependencies as well.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation and solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

@HardcoreHenry explains `make`'s behavior very well in his answer (do not accept this one over that).  I want to point out, however, that `make` has a fair amount of built-in smarts about building software, to the extent that it can do relatively simple builds without any Makefile at all.  Moreover, when you do write a Makefile, it is usually considered good style to minimize repetition.

Thus, I'd suggest this as an *even better* alternative:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 \
  -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare       \
  -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow

speller: speller.o dictionary.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) speller.o dictionary.o
```

That relies on `make` knowing how to build object files from C source files (which it does) and using the C compiler and and flags specified by the `CC` and `CFLAGS` variables when it does so (which it will).  It also uses the special variable `$@`, which, in a rule's recipe, expands to the name of the rule's target.  Some versions of `make` offer even a bit more opportunity to DRY this out.

Among other things, note how the compiler and build flags are specified once each, and near the top.  Now if you ever want to change those, you can do it in one easy-to-find place.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies. When using GNU make, you can skip the `.o` step for small projects and compile the program as a whole

```
speller:  speller.c dictionary.c
         ${CLANG} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $(filter %.c,$^) -o $@ ${LIBS}
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that `make` will recognize a `CLANG` variable that has not explicitly been set, but if you're going to use a variable to specify the C compiler then I don't see why one would prefer `CLANG` over the conventional `CC`.  And of course, at least some of the variables need actually to be set to achieve the build the OP seems to want.